# Oracle output in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have an oracle stored procedure which has output to the users in the form of

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('....');
```

I run the stored procedure through .sql file in sqlplus and none of the output messages of the stored procedures are being shown in sqlplus command window. How could I get the outputs to show in the command window?

Thanks,

Comment: Before running the script, try writing SET SERVEROUTPUT ON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need set your server output to on by this command:

```
SET serveroutput ON;
```

Cheers!

Comment: -_-.. sigh, so simple. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

PhatHV's answer is correct.

Additionally, you can give size if you want in range 2000 through 1000000.
`SET serveroutput ON size 2000;`

For more detail, you can see https://oracleblogging.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/dbms_output-buffer-set-serveroutput-on-size/